# Interested in searching wikipedia xml dump for only medically-related terms

Tags: python, regex, xml, perl, wikipedia

I would like to automatically define medical terms. Standard medical dictionaries and `WordNet`, however, don't suffice. I therefore [downloaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download) the wikipedia corpus to use instead. However, when I downloaded `enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml` (which, incidentally, begins with the word "anarchism"--why not something like "AA"?) I immediately failed with `grep` due to the size of the file, and began looking online. I discovered what I thought to be already-written libraries for this, like Perl's `MediaWiki::DumpFile` (I do know some Perl, but I would prefer Python because that's what my script is written in), but it looks like most of them create or require some kind of database (I just want to (albeit fuzzily) match a word and grab the first few sentences of its introductory paragraph; e.g., a search for '[salmonella](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmonella)' would return :

```
Salmonella /ˌsælməˈnɛlə/ is a genus of rod-shaped (bacillus) bacteria of the Enterobacteriaceae family. There are only two species of Salmonella, Salmonella bongori and Salmonella enterica, of which there are around six subspecies and innumerable serovars. The genus Escherichia, which includes the species E.coli belongs to the same family.Salmonellae are found worldwide in both cold-blooded and warm-blooded animals, and in the environment. They cause illnesses such as typhoid fever, paratyphoid fever, and food poisoning.[1].
```

For my purposes (just using it as a sort of glossary), are these scripts what I want (I find the documentation very difficult to understand without examples)? For example, I would like to:

1. Just to reduce searching material, remove everything that's not medically related (I tried this with a [category](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Categories&offset=M) filter, since Wikipedia allows export of specific categories, but they didn't work as I wanted; for example, 'Medicine' would just return about 20 pages, so I would prefer to just somehow process the xml file).
2. Allow my Python script to quickly search the Wikipedia corpus (for example, if I want to match `CHOLERAE` I would want it to take me to the definition for `Vibrio cholerae` as with the actually Wikipedia search function (just take me to the top choice). I have written a kind of search engine that can do this, but it would be slow with such a large file (40 GB).

Apologies in advance for what's probably a very naive question.

Comment: It sounds to me like scraping wikipedia would be easier... i.e. calling your script would just search wikipedia and return the intro paragraph from the top hit.

Comment: I thought that wasn't allowed..but I agree that it's a bit like reinventing the wheel otherwise

Comment: If this is for your personal/small scale use I'm sure it is fine. If this is being sold or something you should find out more details about the legality...

Comment: Not to discourage you from going the perl XML route (there's lots of tools ready for use) but I believe you can access the Wikipedia data as SQL as well.  If you load that into a database you can query it to your heart's content. It might make it easier to perform any separation of content from markup that might be required. Probably this is going to work best with MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, I will consider that route, @G.Cito. I don't know a lot about MySQL-- is it possible to search with similar results to the actual Wikipedia search?

Comment: My current solution so far is to actually kind of go with @gradi3nt 's suggestion by using the Wikipedia API (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page). I don't think this is really scraping, though? The only drawbacks: 1. I need the precise name of the page, so none of the "top choice from search results" business and 2. I need to somehow now interpret the format. For example, here is what it gives me: `&lt;li id=&quot;cite_note-Brisse&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;mw-cite-backlink&quot;&gt;&lt;b&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;#cite_ref-Brisse_0&quot;&gt;^&lt;/a&gt;&lt;`. Any Python parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to query the Wikipedia database without downloading the whole thing.

```
import requests
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Fetch wikipedia extracts.')
parser.add_argument('word', help='word to define')
args = parser.parse_args()

proxies = {
    # See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page#API_etiquette
    # "http": "http://localhost:3128",
}

headers = {
    # http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page#Identifying_your_client
    "User-Agent": "Definitions/1.0 (Contact rob@example.com for info.)"
}

params = {
    'action':'query',
    'prop':'extracts',
    'format':'json',
    'exintro':1,
    'explaintext':1,
    'generator':'search',
    'gsrsearch':args.word,
    'gsrlimit':1,
    'continue':''
}

r = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
                 params=params,
                 headers=headers,
                 proxies=proxies)
json = r.json()
if "query" in json:
    result = json["query"]["pages"].items()[0][1]["extract"]
    print result.encode('utf-8')
else:
    print "No definition."
```

Here are some results. Note how it still returns a result even if the word is misspelled.

```
$ python define.py CHOLERAE
Vibrio cholerae is a Gram-negative, comma-shaped bacterium. Some strains of V. cholerae cause the disease cholera. V. cholerae is a facultative anaerobic organism and has a flagellum at one cell pole. V. cholerae was first isolated as the cause of cholera by Italian anatomist Filippo Pacini in 1854, but his discovery was not widely known until Robert Koch, working independently 30 years later, publicized the knowledge and the means of fighting the disease.
$ python define.py salmonella
Salmonella /ˌsælməˈnɛlə/ is a genus of rod-shaped (bacillus) bacteria of the Enterobacteriaceae family. There are only two species of Salmonella, Salmonella bongori and Salmonella enterica, of which there are around six subspecies and innumerable serovars. The genus Escherichia, which includes the species E.coli belongs to the same family.
Salmonellae are found worldwide in both cold-blooded and warm-blooded animals, and in the environment. They cause illnesses such as typhoid fever, paratyphoid fever, and food poisoning.
$ python define.py salmanela
Salmonella /ˌsælməˈnɛlə/ is a genus of rod-shaped (bacillus) bacteria of the Enterobacteriaceae family. There are only two species of Salmonella, Salmonella bongori and Salmonella enterica, of which there are around six subspecies and innumerable serovars. The genus Escherichia, which includes the species E.coli belongs to the same family.
Salmonellae are found worldwide in both cold-blooded and warm-blooded animals, and in the environment. They cause illnesses such as typhoid fever, paratyphoid fever, and food poisoning.
```

Comment: WOW! It even takes multiple words in quotes! Brilliant! Greatest dictionary ever!